# Graph proving a cycle inequality

Tags: graph-theory

I was solving some old exams from my university and I've stumbled across this one which I didn't know how tto think through, it says:

Give a graph $H$. Let $u(H)$ be the number of vertices of $H$ of degree 1. Let $C$ be a cycle in $H$. Show that $l(C) <= v(H) - u(H) $

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Can a vertex of degree $1$ belong to $C$?

Comment: By my intuition i know that a vertex of degree 1 can't be a member of that set and that l(C) is <= v(G) but I couldn't figure out how this may help me

Comment: @user71381: The length of $C$ is the number of edges in $C$, which is the same as the number of vertices in $C$. Does that help?